# Filling table with values during migration doesn't work completely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

My *Users* table being quite big, I decided to migrate user profile information to a separate table: *Profiles*. So *Users* table will only have access information (using Devise gem). A *Profile* can have many user accesses.

To do so, I created a migration file to write new data in Profiles table, from Users table:

```
class MigrateSomeUsersInfoToProfilesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    puts "Pulling out profile information from Users table. Can take a while..."
    puts "Start migrating #{User.count} users to `Profiles` table (#{Profile.count} profiles already created)..."

    User.all.each do |u|

      profile = Profile.new({
        first_name: u.first_name,
        last_name: u.last_name,
        picture: u.picture,
        zipcode: u.zipcode,
        bio: u.bio,
        address: u.address,
        latitude: u.latitude,
        longitude: u.longitude,
        gender: u.gender
      })

      if profile.save!
        u.profile_id = profile.id
        u.save!
      else
        puts "ERROR CREATING PROFILE FOR USER #ID #{u.id}"
      end

      puts "CREATED PROFILE ##{profile.id} FOR USER ##{u.id}"

    end
  end

  def down
    Profile.delete_all
  end
end
```

The result is that all profiles were created (the same number as users) and correcly filled. But, the `profile_id` is `nil` for all users. This means that the line `u.profile_id = profile.id` isn't correctly executed.

The only log messages I get are those specified in the migration file (no error or warning messages).

Is there something I missed in the code bellow? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

From `rails console` I get:

```
User.count
=> 2182

Profile.count
=> 2182

User.where("profile_id IS NULL").count
=> 2182
```

**UPDATE 2**

In the app, a real user (defined by the information in Profiles table) can access the app using many emails (personnal, professional,...). In this case, the models are like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

That's why, there is a `profile_id` in the Users table (attribute that is not updated during the migration??)

Comment: could do puts profile.id inside the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `user_id` not `profile_id` if you use the following association:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

# tables
"profiles"
id: integer
user_id: integer

"users"
id: integer
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Comment: Thanks for you answer @itsnikolay. In fact: User `has_one :profile` and Profile `has_many :users`. This way, a unique person (defined by his/her profile) can access his/her account using many email addresses (located in the Users table). This is why Users table has profile_id attribute. I'll update the question.

Comment: Probably you shold use `has_and_belongs_to_many_association` or `has_many ... :trough` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association